# Problem with MATLink use with Mathematica

Tags: matlink

After installing MAThLink I started its use in Mathematica:

```
Needs["MATLink`"]
OpenMATLAB[]
```

I got the following output:

```
MATLink`Engine`engSetVisible[1]
MATLink::errx: Undefined function 'addpath' for input arguments of type 'char'.
```

When I run command

```
MATLink`Developer`GetInfo[]
```

I get the following text:

```
MATLink 1.1 for Windows (Fri 15 Aug 2014)
11.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)
Force 32-bit engine: False
System PATH:
C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.2\SystemFiles\Libraries\Windows-x86-64
C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.2\SystemFiles\Libraries\Windows
C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.2\SystemFiles\Kernel\Binaries\Windows-x86-64
C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.2
C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.2\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\Binaries\Windows-x86-64
C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.2\SystemFiles\Kernel\Binaries\Windows-x86-64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\ComposerXE-2011\redist\intel64\ipp
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\
C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Program Files\SafeNet\Authentication\SAC\x64
C:\Program Files\SafeNet\Authentication\SAC\x32
C:\Program Files (x86)\WebEx\Productivity Tools
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Hitachi ID\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\runtime\win64
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\bin
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\runtime\win64
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\bin
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v84\runtime\win64
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v92\runtime\win64
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v91\runtime\win64
C:\Users\vrubinste\.dnx\bin
C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
C:\Program Files (x86)\Wolfram Research\WolframScript\
C:\Program Files\dotnet\
C:\Users\vrubinste\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\bin\win64
COM server information:
CLSID: {A6581658-356C-4A72-B26C-9D91262CA7E1}
Program ID: Matlab.Application (Version 9.4)
Command: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\bin\win64\MATLAB.exe /MLAutomation
```

What does this error mean?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `CommandWindow` should only be called after `OpenMATLAB`.

Comment: Can you trim down this example to be truly minimal? Is that `CommandWindow` necessary to trigger the error? If not, remove it.  If yes, mention that it is necessary. Do include the output of ``MATLink`Develope`GetInfo[]``

Comment: Without "CommandWindow" same result!

Comment: Please update the question with all the information I requested, otherwise I won't be able to help.

Comment: Do you have spaces in your Windows username?

Comment: @Szabolcs: No I don't have spaces

Comment: The error is coming form MATLAB. MATLink should use `addpath` only in one way, to add the directory ``MATLink`Private`$sessionTemporaryDirectory`` to MATLAB's path. Check what this directory is (*after* `OpenMATLAB[]` only!), then open a separate MATLAB session and see if you can use `addpath` on this directory.

Comment: Another possibility is that you have entries in your MATLAB startup files that cause this (i.e. it's completely unlreated to MATLink)

Comment: @Szabolcs:I have edited my question, did you see full output of `MATLink`Developer`GetInfo[]`

Comment: @Szabolcs:I successfully applied `addpath` command to directory found with `MATLink`Private`$sessionTemporaryDirectory`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm out of ideas for now. I'll have to put this aside for now, and come back later.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thanks for your efforts to help.